# Cite and sort author with lowercase prefix (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

How can I *both* cite and sort an author with a prefix with a lowercase letter in the prefix? Everything in the MWE below is correct, except that I would like the initial `Van Helten` in the bibliography to appear as `van Helten` (note, I still want it to be sorted under `Helten`, as the MWE does).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{vanhelten1891,
    AUTHOR = "W. van Helten",
    TITLE = "Grammatisches",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Beiträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Literatur",
    YEAR = "1891",
    PAGES = "455--488",
    VOLUME = "15"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{vanhelten1891}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might like to add `\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}` to your preamble. This lets `biblatex` think it should not actually start a new sentence and therefore capitalise the name. You might notice an adverse effect with this method if the first field printed ought to be capitalised by `biblatex` automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{vanhelten1891,
    AUTHOR = "W. van Helten",
    TITLE = "Grammatisches",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Beiträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Literatur",
    YEAR = "1891",
    PAGES = "455--488",
    VOLUME = "15"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{vanhelten1891}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

There is also a solution to redefine the name macros to not capitalise the name prefix.
It might look more monstrous but is probably the better way to go for stability.

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       %\ifcapital% comment out
       %  {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}% and get rid of this
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}}}

\renewbibmacro*{name:last}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}
       {}
       {%\ifcapital%<-- commented this out
        %  {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}% and this
          {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
        \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}}%
  \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot}%
```

Comment: This does indeed take care of it. I guess to avoid possible adverse effects, one could come up with something like "If the beginning of the entry is a ``prefix``, use ``\midsentence`` (I can only state my suggestion in prose ... ).

Comment: @Sverre I was thinking about trying to add the `\midsentence` to the name formatting directive instead of putting it in `begentry`. But I refrained from doing so because I thought this to be the cleaner solution, I will investigate though.

Comment: @Sverre You might like a more fundamental redefinition of the name macros as suggested in my macro to get rid of all adverse effects `\midsentence` might have in `begentry`.