# Why does it matter when \AtBeginDocument is run?

Tags: macros, biblatex

As I understood the macro `\AtBeginDocument`, whatever it says will be run right after `\begin{document}`. In other words, it will follow whatever else there is in the preamble. But I've noticed that it matters when in the preamble `\AtBeginDocument` is run. Consider the following example, taken from [Cite and sort author with lowercase prefix (biblatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144877/cite-and-sort-author-with-lowercase-prefix-biblatex).

When the line `\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` is placed before `biblatex` is loaded, the author `van Helten` is sorted under `v` in the bibliography. The `biblatex` option `useprefix` has in other words been changed to `true`. This is expected, since `\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}` is activated at the beginning of the document, thus overriding the option `useprefix = false` which was set in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, useprefix = false]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{vanhelten1891,
    AUTHOR = "W. van Helten",
    TITLE = "Grammatisches",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Beiträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Literatur",
    YEAR = "1891",
    PAGES = "455--488",
    VOLUME = "15"}
@BOOK{mccartney1967,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Hey Jude",
    YEAR = "1967"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{vanhelten1891}{mccartney1967}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

But when `\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` is placed *after* `biblatex` is loaded, the author `van Helten` is sorted under `h` in the bibliography. The `biblatex` option `useprefix = false` has in other words not been overridden by `\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}`. Why is this? Shouldn't `\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` be executed last anyway, and therefore override whatever the option `useprefix` is set to in the preamble?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, useprefix = false]{biblatex}
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{vanhelten1891,
    AUTHOR = "W. van Helten",
    TITLE = "Grammatisches",
    JOURNALTITLE = "Beiträge zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und Literatur",
    YEAR = "1891",
    PAGES = "455--488",
    VOLUME = "15"}
@BOOK{mccartney1967,
    AUTHOR = "Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Hey Jude",
    YEAR = "1967"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\cites{vanhelten1891}{mccartney1967}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\AtBeginDocument` macro appends its contents to a token list, which is expanded right after `\begin{document}`. Hence, if you first issue `\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` and `biblatex` appends `\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}`, because it is loaded afterwards the togglefalse part stands last and "wins".

Comment: @HenriMenke You mean that ``biblatex`` also appends ``\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}`` to the same "token list" that ``\AtBeginDocument`` appends ``\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}`` to?

Comment: That's my guess. I don't know for sure, but you can of course look it up in the `biblatex` code.

Comment: Just like I guessed: `\AtBeginDocument{...\blx@bblinput...}` where `\def\blx@bblinput{...\blx@blxinit...}` and `\appto\blx@blxinit{...\def\ifuseprefix{\iftoggle{blx@useprefix}...}`. Hence `\toggle____{blx@useprefix}` is buried deep inside `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Sorry, `\AtBeginDocument` is not a token list, but a macro, which is extended via `\g@addto@macro` on every occurrence.

Comment: I don't really understand this. If you or someone could provide a dumbed-down answer, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `\AtBeginDocument` macro appends its contents to the macro `\@begindocumenthook` which is expanded right after `\begin{document}`. Hence, if you first issue `\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}` and `biblatex` appends `\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}` (due to `useprefix=false`), because it is loaded afterwards the togglefalse part stands last and "wins".

If we look inside `biblatex1.sty`, we can see

```
\AtBeginDocument{...\blx@bblinput...}
...
\def\blx@bblinput{...\blx@blxinit...}
...
\appto\blx@blxinit{...\def\ifuseprefix{\iftoggle{blx@useprefix}}...}
```

If we now consider expansion then this is equivalent to

```
\AtBeginDocument{...\def\ifuseprefix{\iftoggle{blx@useprefix}}...}
```

Keeping this in mind, your code

```
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}}
\usepackage[style=authoryear, useprefix = false]{biblatex}
```

reduces to something like

```
\AtBeginDocument{\toggletrue{blx@useprefix}\togglefalse{blx@useprefix}}
```

where `\togglefalse` is being executed **after** `\toggletrue`, hence the switch is set to false at `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 7):

If you (or a packages you load) go

```
\AtBeginDocument{\newcommand\zz{}}
```

...

```
\AtBeginDocument{\zz}
```

Then just before the document starts, LaTeX will do

```
\newcommand\zz{}\zz
```

and nothing bad will happen.

Now, if you load packages in another order so the effective usage is:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\zz}
```

...

```
\AtBeginDocument{\newcommand\zz{}}
```

then at the start of the document LaTeX will do

```
\zz\newcommand\zz{}
```

and generate an undefined command error as `\zz` is used before it is defined.

Comment: But this is because the order of macros internally to ``\AtBeginDocument`` is wrong. That's not quite the scenario illustrated in my question, is it?

Comment: @Sverre It is not exactly your scenario, but it shows, that the order of `\AtBeginDocument` statements is very important.

Comment: @Sverre more or less but just using simpler code. Basically I wanted to highlight that it only matters if two things are added to the begin document hook as the order they are executed is the order they are added, so the expectation should be that it matters when you use this hook (if you suspect any package you are using uses it) the exact details of what goes wrong in each case differ of course

Comment: @HenriMenke Yes, but this is about the order of multiple instances of ``\AtBeginDocument``. It seems rather straightforward that that order matters when those commands are executed.

Comment: @Sverre your question is all about multiple instances of AtBeginDocument the ones you do and the ones biblatex does

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The implication here being that ``biblatex`` also adds something to the "begin document hook"? EDIT: Ok, I see (I didn't know that ``biblatex`` used ``\AtBeginDocument`` internally).

Comment: @Sverre Well that is implied by your question otherwise the order wouldn't matter (I didn't actually look:-) but Henri already confirmed that is the case in a comment on your question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was precisely because I thought the order didn't matter that I couldn't understand why it did matter in this case ... ``:)``.