# Mixing listoffigures, cleveref, and a custom class using AtBeginDocument

Tags: table-of-contents, cleveref

Here's a MWE of my problem. Using the following document

```
\documentclass{report}
\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{This caption cross-references \cref{eqn}.}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation} F = ma \label{eqn}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

results in a document that looks like this:

[image]

However, if I remove the `\listoffigures` command from `\AtBeginDocument` and instead directly call it in the tex file (right after `\begin{document}`), I get this:

[image]

Evidently, in the first case `cleveref` can't figure out the type of reference, while in the second case it can. What is the difference between these two?

My real use case is a large LaTeX document class file that provides various customizations to the `report` class, one of which is to create the list of figures automatically, i.e, without the user needing to remember to insert the instruction `\listoffigures`. How can I get the correct information embedded in the document for `cleveref` to parse when using the first approach?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code to simplify it to the absolute minimum needed to generate the screenshot you posted. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I cut down a 1400 line class file and a 10000 line document to my original MWE trying to isolate the problem... it didn't occur to me to take the last step and move the `AtBeginDocument` out of a class file entirely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, the instruction `\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}` ends up making sure that the `\listoffigures` is "queued up" *before* LaTeX has a chance to "learn" what `\cref` means.

A solution would be to instruct the class file to load the `cleveref` package as well -- and to do so *before* issuing the directive `\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}`.

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}
```

Comment: How does `AtBeginDocument` actually work? The way it's written, I assumed it was analogous to a preprocessor macro in C, i.e. the commands it contained would be textually expanded when `\begin{document}` is called. However, this problem clearly indicates that all the commands it contains are actually executed immediately, but somehow "queued up" like you said. The naming made me expect a lazier execution pattern, how does it handle the queuing?

Comment: @Vyas - Just how `\AtBeginDocument` works is a very interesting question indeed. :-) Even though I think I have a pretty good grasp of what this instruction does, my understanding is nowhere near as thorough as that of some of the other, truly expert-level users who frequent this site. May I therefore suggest that you post a new query, in which you'd ask for an in-depth explanation of what `\AtBeginDocument` does? (To motivate why you're asking the new query, you could provide a link to the present query.) I'm sure that this new query would be of great interest to many users.

Comment: [Done](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565206/when-and-how-are-commands-in-atbegindocument-evaluated)! Please add whatever tags you think might be appropriate to get attention from the right people, I thought documentclass-writing was about right but maybe there are other useful tags for builtin Latex2e commands.

Comment: @Vyas why do you say that this indicates the commands are executed immediately? they are not, they are simply stored and executed at begin document/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the original sequence of my commands was `AtBeginDocument{...} \usepackage{cleveref} \begin{document}...`. If the contents of `AtBeginDocument` are "simply stored and executed at `\begin{document}`", then switching the order to `\usepackage{cleveref} AtBeginDocument{...} \begin{document}...` should have no effect. Therefore, my conclusion was that _something_ must be happening prior to the `\begin{document}` that is triggered by `AtBeginDocument` for this sequence change to fix the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177397/why-does-it-matter-when-atbegindocument-is-run) answers my question, though. You (and my original assumption) are probably right that execution is delayed until `\begin{document}`, but the issue is that `cleveref` is _also_ probably depending on adding commands to `AtBeginDocument` and the sequence in which they're added is causing the problems.

Comment: @Vyas yes look at cleverref.sty it is essentially `\AtBeginDocument{a}\AtBeginDocument{b}` so moving your atbegindocument is just asking why `\AtBeginDocument{you}\AtBeginDocument{a}\AtBeginDocument{b}` is different to `\AtBeginDocument{a}\AtBeginDocument{b}\AtBeginDocument{you}`  they all get delayed then at begin document, one does `you a b` and the other does `a b you`.