# When and how are commands in the argument of \AtBeginDocument evaluated?

Tags: packages, documentclass-writing

This question is motivated as a followup to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565170/mixing-listoffigures-cleveref-and-a-custom-class-using-atbegindocument/565201?noredirect=1#comment1424252_565201), where I ran into an issue with subtle differences in execution order between a `usepackage` command and `AtBeginDocument`. To simplify the discussion, I'll reproduce the main code here:

```
\documentclass{report}
\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} \caption{This caption cross-references \cref{eqn}.} \label{fig} \end{figure}
\begin{equation} F = ma \label{eqn}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Paraphrasing [a comment I posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565170/mixing-listoffigures-cleveref-and-a-custom-class-using-atbegindocument/565201?noredirect=1#comment1424251_565201) in response to the answer there, my assumption from the naming was that `\AtBeginDocument` would behave like a preprocessor macro in C or something similar to that, i.e. it would be lazily expanded and evaluated when it was run (at the beginning of the document). However, the issue I ran into was caused by running a `\usepackage` command in the preamble of my document after `\AtBeginDocument` was called in my cls file, and it was resolved when I moved the `usepackage` call above `AtBeginDocument`, indicating that it's immediately executing the commands but somehow delaying their effect until `\begin{document}`. Specifically, this order led to `cleveref` not knowing how to refer to equations in the figure captions copied into the `lof`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{...}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

whereas swapping those two commands fixed that issue. So my question is, how does `\AtBeginDocument` work, and what assumptions can I actually make about when its arguments are evaluated and when their side effects will become apparent?

Comment: Traditionally `\AtBeginDocument{<stuff>}` would just append `<stuff>` to a hook that is executed at `\begin{documen}`. So `\AtBeginDocument{<A>}\AtBeginDocument{<B>}` would execute `<A>` and then `<B>` at `\begin{document}`. Since some packages use `\AtBeginDocument` you can sometimes get different results when you move `\AtBeginDocument` before or after a `\usepackage`. But the LaTeX version released tonight (LaTeX 2020-10-01) has a much more sophisticated hook mechanism that makes it possible to have finer control over `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/177397/35864 for an example that explains why order matters. Anyway, I think `\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}` might be a bit dangerous. I'm not sure if `\AtBeginDocument` is supposed to contain typesettable content. Usually it contains setup and config code.

Comment: If you want to typeset stuff at the beginning of your document, `etoolbox` suggests `\AfterEndPreamble` (which probably has a 'native' LaTeX hook equivalent in the 2020-10-01 release).

Comment: I haven't looked at the `cleveref` code to find out what is actually going on here, but I know that `cleveref` uses `\AtBeginDocument` quite extensively. So I'd guess if you say `\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}\usepackage{cleveref}` the begin document hook contains `\listoffigures <cleveref initialisation code>` and if you say `\usepackage{cleveref}\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}` you get `<cleveref initialisation code> \listoffigures`. The latter gives the expected result, the former doesn't if `\litsoffigures` uses `cleveref` commands.

Comment: @moewe I hope you are OK with my answer: this is more or less the same as your comments but I was writing as you were commenting!

Comment: @JosephWright Absolutely! I wrote a comment precisely because I didn't want to discourage someone who actually knows about the new hook mechanism from writing an answer.

Comment: your initial assumption was right, the argument is just stored without being evaluated and is evaluated within the code for begin document.

Comment: DavidCarlisle sorry to spam you between these two threads, I just finished reading through this conversation and @moewe's comments and the other post he linked to helped clear up my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tokens added using `\AtBeginDocument` appear in exactly the order they are added, which is why reordering the preamble makes a difference. From the latest LaTeX release (2020-10-01) there is a new hook mechanism which allows re-ordering based on sorting rules: `\AddToHook{begindocument}`. However, as commented, `\AtBeginDocument` or the new `\AddToHook{begindocument}` equivalent should not be used for anything typeset. For that, you should use `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}` with a new LaTeX format or load `etoolbox` and use `\AfterEndPreamble` hook.

Comment: @Vyas - I think that the likely upshot of this answer is that because you can't (shouldn't?) assume that all users of your LaTeX document class will be using the 2020-10-01 (or later) version of the LaTeX kernel and hence won't have access to the `\AddToHook` device, you should replace `\AtBeginDocument{\listoffigures}` with `\usepackage{etoolbox} \AfterEndPreamble{\listoffigures}`. :-)

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, thanks for the help!